# Angular - Error with cheerio package? "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am suddenly facing this issue that seemingly came out of nowhere. The project I am working on in my company is rather large and we are using a micro frontend architecture. I was working in one branch yesterday and after building and pushing my code, I checked out to another branch to check something and then went back to the original branch I was in. After trying to serve the application again, I was faced with this error. It seems everyone else on the team is getting this error, too. Even those who haven't pulled the code I pushed.

Here is the error:

Error: ./node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/esm/index.js 59:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (59:9)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |     return getFeed(parseDOM(feed, options));
  | }

> export * as DomUtils from "domutils";
> | // Old name for DomHandler
> | export { DomHandler as DefaultHandler };

Error: ./node_modules/cheerio/node_modules/parse5/dist/index.js 6:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:9)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | export { serialize, serializeOuter } from './serializer/index.js';
  | /** @internal */

> export * as foreignContent from './common/foreign-content.js';
> | /** @internal */
> | export * as html from './common/html.js';

I've tried:

- updating cheerio
- deleting node_modules and package-lock, then running npm i
- deleting cheerio
- reverting back to before I pushed my code

Really not sure what else to do. This is my first stack overflow question so sorry if I'm missing any necessary info.

EDIT: I found two links on github

https://github.com/umijs/umi/issues/8109

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/2545

and after following their instructions, I added cheerio to dev dependencies in package.json and then installed the 'stream' package. The error is resolved for the time being.